# How to use a partial in ZF?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I am trying to load a partial view in the index page. In order to do so in the index.phtml I have the following:

```
echo $this->partial('index/partials/categories.phtml', array('categoryFeed'=>$this->categoryFeed));
```

The problem is that when I load the partial, it will also load the header and footer (from the layout), so I will have *index[header-partial[header-content-footer]-footer]*. 
My question is, how can I load a partial in the homepage?

Comment: To me the question is not clear. What's the problem? What do you want to do and what happens instead?

Comment: is the path to your partial correct, it seems to me that it is executing an action thus enabling the layout. check out this link http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/zend/using-partial-helpers-in-zend-framework/

Comment: @Bodman: yes, I think you're right. In your link, the partial view helper it's used inside the layout file.  I would like to use it inside the index file (index.phtml), but I don't know how to do it the right way (I'm new to ZF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partial view helper clones current view object, clears assigned vars in cloned view and executes specified view script.

It can't load additional header-footer-whatever.
Check your partial view script.